# iphone : Poor UIImageView Performance

Tags: iphone

Hello Every one I'm working on google maps app for iphone i'm stuck with the way the UIImagView created moves on the screen, Besides that i have created 3*3 UIImageViews so that i can gather good amount of data on one go...

But the movement of image not good i'm doing

horizontalOffset = mapCenterImgView.center.x;

final_x = touch.x - horizontalOffset;

mapCenterImgView.frame = CGRectMake(final_x, 0, 320, 490);

This for center image... But smooth and sliding is not achievable  besides when i do some what similar approach for other views it causes complete mess all round...

Please suggest something to improve my condition... Please >>>

Comment: This is very difficult to advise on without seeing the code.

Are you trying to drag the images? In which case, are you using a UIScrollView?

Comment: I have tired using the UIScrollView but no help as it allows on Vertical scroll. I also want to have the Horizontal scroll... And yes I'm trying to drag the image from one place to another... but it give jerky and non-steady movement

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an UIImageView, you can easily use quartz's built-in animation functions!

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-basic-animations-on-iphone